# Multiple sideEffects in Gremlin Neptune query?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a gremlin query that uses a sideEffect to store the common movies that friends have rated positively. I would like to add tv_shows vertices to the query. Does this require a separate sideEffect? Thanks!

```
g.V('c3833064-94aa-4084-9c0e-029543d69892').as('self')
.sideEffect(out('rated').store('movies'))
.out('friended')
.group()
.by()
.by(outE('rated')
.where(values('rating').is(gt(5)))  //filter on positive scores on common rated items
.inV()
.where(within('movies')).count())
.order(local)
.by(values,desc)
.unfold().limit(10)
.select(keys)
.project('id','label','username', 'avatarUrl', 'name')
.by(id)
.by(label)
.by('username')
.by(coalesce(values('avatarUrl'), constant('')))
.by('name')
```

Comment: Does `out('rated')` only find movies today? Are TV shows found using a different edge label?

Comment: Yes, only movies. No, it's the same edge label. out('rated') would work for tv_shows, too.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question. If `out('rated')` will already find Movies and TV Shows, what is the specific ask? Is it to somehow reflect in the results the type of show/movie watched? Maybe a different grouping? You can write the query many ways. I all really depends on what you want to final results to look like.

Comment: Hi, Kelvin. Thanks for responding. Right now the query returns a users' friends who have rated the same movie positively in descending order of how many common positive ratings were made. I just want to modify it so that another vertex (tv_shows) is included in the results. The new results should return users who have rated the most similar movies AND tv_shows in descending order number of common positive ratings.

Comment: the app has ratings for tv_shows will eventually include other types of media. are you saying that the query above will already return friend-based ratings data for any vertex that has a 'rated' edge? so i don't need to change anything?

Comment: Yes, when you do `out('rated').store('movies')` you are capturing anything on the other end of that `rated` edge. So if there are also TV shows there, you will be capturing those as well.